# 1 class implements 2 listeners - ошибка

Tags: java, android, listener, extension

Пишу приложение в Android Studio. Хочу в одном классе реализовать два разных слушателя.
Вот часть моего кода:

```
MyFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    //my fields
    private Spinner mySpinner;
    @Ovveride
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
        //мой код
    }

    @Ovveride public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>p){}

    @Ovveride
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //мой код
    }

    @Ovveride
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        //мой код
        mySpinner = (Spinner) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

На последней строке я получил ошибку:

> 'setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)' in 'android.widget.AdapterView' cannot be applied to '(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)'

Как исправить эту ошибку?
[На enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048513/implement-multiple-event-listeners-in-the-same-fragment-android) пишут, что так делать можно.

Comment: checkbox не является классом, работающим с адаптером (в отличии от спиннера по вашей ссылке) и вы не можете использовать данный слушатель с простым View, о чем вам и сказано в ошибке. для чекбокса используется слушатель OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: @pavlofff, прошу прощенья, неверно переписал код. OnItemSelectedListener я вешал на Spinner.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас `myCheckBox` это `CheckBox` то навесить `action` можно таким способом

```
myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});
```

Интерфейс `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` относится к `spinner`. Метод `onItemSelected` отрабатывает только на нажатие на пункт в `spinner`

Comment: Это мне и самому понятно. Меня интересует, можно ли так использовать тот способ?

Comment: `MyFragment` может реализовать сколь угодно слушателей

Comment: c несколькими слушателями не компилируется. Выдает ошибку. Может я че-то неправильно сделал?

Comment: Вообще-то метод `onItemSelected` отрабатывает на нажатие на пункт не только в `spinner`, а в любом `AdapterView`, например, в `ListView`.

Comment: Я имел ввиду тот пример который в ссылке оставили

Answer (score 0):

Я лоханулся, у меня строчка `mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` находилась в локальном классе, о чем и написано в ошибке, поэтому надо было написать `MyFragment.this`.